# Block/Closure Understanding

Tags: ios, swift, closures, block

Need clarification on blocks and closure.

1. How blocks will retain the object? or why we need to use only weak inside block? What will happen if we don't follow this? Or please give some clarity on block.
2. The below one os for closure.

I have written some code like this. `favouriteButton` is a property of self.

```
favouriteButton.hidden = false
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self._collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

It didn't gave any error. So I thought of doing UI in main thread. So I moved the code to disable hidden inside block like below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  favouriteButton.hidden = false
  self._collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

It shows an error like

> reference to property 'favouriteButton' in closure requires explicit
>   'self'

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.favouriteButton.hidden = false
  self._collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Could any one please explain how to use closure/block effectively.

3. Does the blocks and closures work in the same way?

Answer (score 4):

In Swift (and Objective-C), a block is a closure.  The term *closure* refers to an individually-executable block of code that captures the values of variables in the enclosing scope.  In the case of Swift, the enclosing scope is usually a function, and only variables used within the block are captured.

The reason you need to preface class-level references (properties and function calls) with `self.` is to make explicit the capturing of `self`.  Doing so allows you to specify how `self` (or any other object reference) is captured: strong (default) or weak.

There are two reasons to be careful with retaining objects (keeping strong references) within a block.

1. The most common concern is creating a retain cycle.  This is where the block retains a strong reference to an object, which in turn has a strong reference to the block.  Until one of the references is explicitly broken, neither the block, nor the object, will be released.  (Releasing a block simply cleans up the captured variables.  The executable code remains.)
2. A strong reference to an object within a block can keep the object alive longer than intended.  For example, if a block keeps a reference to a view controller that is popped off a navigation stack, you likely don't want that block to act on the view controller when its executed.  This can be avoided by capturing a weak reference to the view controller.  This allows the view controller to be deallocated when it's popped, and the block becomes a no-op.